# How do I say these situations, according to the runway's status?

Tags: phraseology, closed-runways

There is an accident on the runway, for example, the aircraft is disabled on it, so, the runway is_________.
The runway is flooded, or there is oil spill on it, so, the runway is______.
Closed? Unserviceable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the US, you would use "closed". From the [FAA's Pilot/Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg.pdf):

> CLOSED RUNWAY− A runway that is unusable for aircraft operations. Only
>   the airport management/ military operations office can close a runway

And this is part of the example ATIS broadcast from the same document:

> Left approach in use, Runway Two Five Right closed, advise you have
>   Alfa.

I don't know if ICAO uses a different term, but "closed" is probably going to be clear to most pilots (and non-pilots, for that matter).

Comment: Occasionally I'll hear over ATIS "Runway XY closed for snow removal" or painting, or whatever, they don't have to explain it, but at my local airport they run through the airport NOTAM's on the ATIS.